# Why setState throw Objects are not valid as a React child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an error when trying to use `this.setState(...)`

```
  state = {
    results: {},
    isFinished: false,
    activeQuestion: 0,
    answerState: null,
    quiz: [],
    loading: true
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const resp = await axios.get(`/quizes/${this.props.match.params.id}.json`);
      const quiz = resp.data;
      this.setState({
        quiz,
        loading: false
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

My server request successful return an array, but when I trying to set it value into the local state I got the error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {errorMessage, label, touched, valid, validation, value}). If you
>   meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
>       in span (at ActiveQuiz.js:9)
>       in p (at ActiveQuiz.js:8)
>       in div (at ActiveQuiz.js:7)
>       in ActiveQuiz (at Quiz.js:109)
>       in div (at Quiz.js:98)
>       in div (at Quiz.js:97)
>       in Quiz (created by Route)
>       in Route (at App.js:16)
>       in Switch (at App.js:13)
>       in main (at Layout.js:37)
>       in div (at Layout.js:24)
>       in Layout (at App.js:12)
>       in App (at src/index.js:10)
>       in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>       in Brodetailuter (at src/index.js:9)

And ditail:

```
  21 | const resp = await axios.get(`/quizes/${this.props.match.params.id}.json`);   
  22 | const quiz = resp.data;   
  23 | 
> 24 | this.setState({   
  25 |   quiz,   
  26 |   loading: false   
  27 | })
```

If I logging `quiz` object I got `[{}]` in the console. And all the underlying components got props successfully.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={classes.Quiz}>
        <div className={classes.QuizWrapper}>
          <h1>Please answere:</h1>
          {
            this.state.loading
              ? <Loader/>
              : this.state.isFinished
              ? <FinishedQuiz
                results={this.state.results}
                quiz={this.state.quiz}
                onRetry={this.onRetryHandler}
              />
              : <ActiveQuiz
                answers={this.state.quiz[this.state.activeQuestion].answers}
                question={this.state.quiz[this.state.activeQuestion].question}
                onAnswerClick={this.onAnswerClickHandler}
                quizLength={this.state.quiz.length}
                answerNumber={this.state.activeQuestion + 1}
                state={this.state.answerState}
              />
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I checked with debugger props into `ActiveQuiz` is correct.

Please, help me fix it. Why it can happen and how to fix it?

**UPDATE 1**

```
const ActiveQuiz = props => {
  debugger
  return (
    <div className={classes.ActiveQuiz}>
      <p className={classes.Question}>
      <span>
        <strong>{props.answerNumber}.</strong>&nbsp;
        {props.question}
      </span>

        <small>{props.answerNumber} из { props.quizLength }</small>
      </p>

      <AnswersList
        state={props.state}
        answers={props.answers}
        onAnswerClick={props.onAnswerClick}
      />
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: The error message clearly shows the cause is ActiveQuiz component. It would be more helpful if you show the `render` method of ActiveQuiz also

Comment: Your problem looks like a collection inside `ActiveQuiz` - the error says you have a collection but it isn't really an array. I'm guessing the line numbers are off.

Comment: whatever has structure of `{errorMessage, label, touched, valid, validation, value}` you should explicitly render that with wrapping with some tags/components. Currently you just trying to render it directly like `<div>{this.props.whatever}</div>`

Comment: most likely you are using an object in render in your ActiveQuiz component whereas it needs a react component

Comment: @Firman Wijaya I add ActiveQuiz to question.

Comment: @skyboyer yes You right I'm trying call `{props.question}` instead `{props.question.value}` inside ActiveQuiz. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error states that it has encountered an object, due to which it is unable to render the output. It also states, that the error occurs at line `<span>`. Since your `activeQuestion` is an `int`. Hence your `answerNumber` prop shouldn't be at fault.

My guess would be, it has something to do with your data structure of `props.question`. Maybe what you are trying to render is an object / nested object due to which an error is thrown that it is not valid.

Hope it helps :)